# How can I write events to the XEvent Profiler

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ssms

Is there a way to write a string to the XEvent profiler that will then put it in the profiler output? What I want to do is in my `OnInitializeAsync()` method (my app is Blazor Server using Entity Framework) is write to the XProfiler event list at the start, and again at the end of the method. That way I can see what SQL queries occurred in that method.

If there is no explicit way to do this, would I have any problems doing the following (it works, just asking if it's going to cause me problems)

```
if (debugMode) {
    await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync("-- starting Dashboard.OnInitializeAsync()");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `RAISERROR` (sic) work for this purpose?

Comment: The profiler etc listens to queries, you don't send it things, so the best is to run some queries. You can also set some specific applicationName to your connection string so it's easy to filter out "your" queries from the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedure [sp_trace_generateevent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-trace-generateevent-transact-sql) may be used to generate an event of type `user_event`, which can be captured by a SQL Trace or Extended Event session. Specify a value of 82 through 91 for the @eventid parameter and the desired text for @userinfo:

```
if (debugMode) {
    await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync("EXEC sp_trace_generateevent @eventid = 82, @userinfo = N'starting Dashboard.OnInitializeAsync()';");
}
```

The pre-defined XEvent Profiler `Standard` and `TSQL` sessions do not capture `user_event` but you can include it in a custom XE session along with other XE events of interest. Below is example DDL to create a custom session with the same events as the XEvent Profiler `Standard` quick trace plus `user_event`. After creation, the session can be started/viewed/stopped from SSMS similarly to other XE sessions.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [CustomQuickSessionStandard] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.attention(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0)))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
    ACTION(package0.callstack,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.tsql_stack)
    WHERE ([severity]>=(20) OR ([error_number]=(17803) OR [error_number]=(701) OR [error_number]=(802) OR [error_number]=(8645) OR [error_number]=(8651) OR [error_number]=(8657) OR [error_number]=(8902) OR [error_number]=(41354) OR [error_number]=(41355) OR [error_number]=(41367) OR [error_number]=(41384) OR [error_number]=(41336) OR [error_number]=(41309) OR [error_number]=(41312) OR [error_number]=(41313)))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.existing_connection(SET collect_options_text=(1)
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.login(SET collect_options_text=(1)
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.logout(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0)))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0)))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_starting(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0)))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.user_event(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=16384 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=5 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=PER_CPU,TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any downside to my `ExecuteSqlAsync("-- comment")` approach? Because that seems a lot easier. TIA

Comment: A downside to the embedded comment approach is you'll need to parse the SQL text for all events regardless of whether the batch or rpc request actually contains debug info. Maybe that's not a big deal for your use case but separate events to delineate calls within the method is more flexible, IMHO.